# QSerialPort fails to open "/dev/ttyUSB0" on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

I'm trying to connect a micro-controller with my desktop PC via a USB serial cable.
The OS of my desktop PC is Ubuntu 13.10. The USB serial cable is [TTL-232R-3V3](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) (FTDI).

Here is my source code. When running the program, it end up in failure. 
(In this case, "Fail" was printed on console.)

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSerialPort/QtSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    // Example use QSerialPortInfo
    QSerialPort serial("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    if (serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        qDebug() << "Pass\n";
        serial.close();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Fail\n";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

According to [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qtserialport-index.html), following statement have to be added in .pro file.

```
QT += serialport
```

When the USB serial cable is plugged in, it is recognized as "/dev/ttyUSB0" on Ubuntu.
It seems to work well.

```
$dmesg | grep ttyUSB
>>[   27.653383] usb 6-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0

$ls -la | grep ttyUSB
>> crw-rw----   1 root dialout 188,   0 12月 14 17:30 ttyUSB0
```

In order to avoid permission troubles, my username is added to *dialout* group by *gpasswd* command. As a result, I can communicate with the USB serial device on terminal software.

But I cannot resolve the QSerialPort problem. Does anyone have any ideas?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check serial.error() and serial.errorString(). You might also have to set properties such as baud rate first.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks to your advice, I understood the reason for the problem.  serial.error() returns 2, seria.errorString() returns "device or resource busy while trying to open". Perhaps the zombie processes of terminal software made device busy. It works after rebooting my desktop PC. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank suggested, you can always get the error diagnostics with errorString(). See our examples for details.

I cannot reproduce the problem, but based on your comment, your serial port was already used by another process, so this means it is not a QtSerialPort issue. Any other software would have had an issue with this, e.g. a new minicom session.

Glad that it works now. :)